# heat equation with perfectly insulated end

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, physics, partial-derivative, heat-equation

In one of my tutorial question about $1$-dim heat equation,a question about heat equation with pefectly insulated end at $x=0$ and $x=l$ with
${\rm u}\left(\, x,t\,\right)$ as temperature function,TAs used as perfectly insulated end implies $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{(0,t)}=0$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{(l,t)}=0$,but if perfectly insulated end means temperature at that point remains constant,then correct expression should be like $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}|_{(0,t)}=0 $and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}|_{(l,t)}=0$ right? (it means $u$ is independent of t at that point, am I right?)

How did the former equation represent perfectly insulated ends? What is the physical meaning of these each expression, i.e., $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{(0,t)}=0 \ \hbox{ and  } \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}|_{(0,t)}=0$$ also similar expression like $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{(x,0)}=0$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}|_{(x,0)}=0$ in context of heat transfer environment, what does each quantity represent?

What is wrong with my understanding about partial derivative? please help me...
note:$u(x,t)$ is temperature at cordinate $x$ at time $t$

Comment: You cannot specify the derivative in $t$ at $t=0$. This is a first order equation in time $t$. So you can specify the value of the function at $t=0$, but not its derivative in $t$ at $t=0$.

Comment: I can take partial derivative w.r.t $t$ and put $t=0$,right?,is that correct?

Comment: If you were solving $f'+af=0$, the only natural condition would be to specify the value of $f$ at a point, but not the value of $f'$. The heat equation is first order in $t$. If you have an equation that is second order, then you would expect to set the value of the function and its derivative, but not the value of the second order derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of the physics.  The heat flow $Q$ is proportional to the gradient of the temperature $u$:

$$Q = -k \mathbf{\nabla}u$$

where $k$ is a heat conductivity.  In a perfectly insulated material, there is no heat flow. Hence, the temperature gradient is zero.  In 1D, this translates to the spatial derivative of $u$, as stated in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer for your original question "why ∂u∂x|(0,t)=0 and ∂u∂x|(l,t) represents a perfectly insulated surface":

In heat transfer if surface if perfectly insulated so that means No heat flow through this surface which means that the heat flow streamlines is parallel to this surface which in your case a vertical line at x=0, x=l, so `∂Ψ/∂y=0. and as we know ∂Ψ/∂y = ∂u/∂x`  "Cauchy Riemann conditions" so you get ∂u/∂x=0 at this boundaries.

This is my own interpretation.

I hope that may help you.